# Getting "Omnichannel Inventory and B2C Commerce Enablement Failed" error when trying to enable Omnichannel in Salesforce

Tags: community

I have a Salesforce Order Management enabled in my SF org as well as this org is integrated with SFCC sandbox so I can get orders from there.
I need to enable Omnichannel Inventory but I'm getting the below error ("Omnichannel Inventory and B2C Commerce Enablement Failed") when trying to do this:

[image: Error text: "Omnichannel Inventory and B2C Commerce Enablement Failed"]

It also happens when I'm trying to enable "Omnichannel Inventory"(the first option showed on the screenshot) - Error text: "Omnichannel Inventory Enablement Failed" .

Does anyone have any idea about why this is happening or what might be causing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have OCI license? You get OCI license either by purchasing OM or by getting the SKU through being a B2C customer

Comment: @Swetha , I was able to activate OM on my dev edition org without any licenses. That's why I thought the OCI should be available the same way so that I could test its capabilities.
Could you please also provide some more details as to getting the SKU from B2C?